# Rotational invariance of the conductivity tensor (Classical Hall Effect)

Tags: electromagnetism, symmetry, hall-effect

In classical Hall effect, the conductivity tensor is given as

$\sigma = \frac{\sigma_{DC}}{1+\omega_B^2 \tau^2} \begin{pmatrix}
1 & -\omega_B \tau \\ \omega_B \tau & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

where the author suggests that since it is rotationally invariant, it must be in the form of

$\sigma = \frac{\sigma_{DC}}{1+\omega_B^2 \tau^2} \begin{pmatrix}
1 & -\omega_B \tau \\ \omega_B \tau & 1
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
\sigma_{xx} & \sigma_{xy} \\ -\sigma_{xy} & \sigma_{xx}
\end{pmatrix}$.

My understanding of rotational invariance is that of

$\forall A \in SO(2), \quad A^T \sigma A = \sigma$ , i.e. $[\sigma, A]=0$, which would result in that form as outlined in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173639/properties-for-a-matrix-being-invariant-under-rotation.

However, I want to know what it really means physically; $\sigma$ is a conductivity, hence a tensor, which used to be a scalar when magnetic field is absent. So what does it mean that the conductivity is rotationally invariant?

Comment: "the author suggests..."  - which author?

Comment: This is from Lecture notes on Quantum Hall Effect by David Tong. It is from the first chapter, 1.2.2 The Drude model.

Comment: Conductivity is a rank-2 tensor which means that $\sigma'_{ij}=R_{ik}R_{jl}\sigma_{kl}$ where $R$ is the rotation matrix. What is the problem here? Rotational invariance means the case $\sigma'_{ij}=\sigma_{ij}$

Answer (score 1):

A generic $n\times n$ matrix $\sigma$ can be decomposed as
$$\sigma = \sigma_0 + \sigma_H + \sigma_S$$
where $\sigma_0$ is proportional to the identity matrix, $\sigma_H$ is antisymmetric, and $\sigma_S$ is symmetric and trace-free.  Explicitly for $2\times 2$ matrices,
$$\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}=\frac{a+b}{2} \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1} + \frac{b-c}{2}\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0} + \Delta \pmatrix{\cos(\varphi)&\sin(\varphi)\\ \sin(\varphi)&-\cos(\varphi)} $$
where $\Delta \equiv \sqrt{\left(\frac{a-d}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{b+c}{2}\right)^2} $ and $\tan(\varphi)=\frac{b+c}{a-d}$.

Writing $\mathbf E = \sigma \mathbf J$, we can examine the contributions to $\mathbf E$ from the various parts of $\sigma$.  The scalar part contributes a scalar multiple of $\mathbf J$, while the antisymmetric part contributes a component which is orthogonal to $\mathbf J$.

The symmetric part requires additional interpretation.  It defines two special directions in the plane, offset by $\varphi$ from the chosen reference axes. $\mathbf J$ is resolved into its components along these special axes, scaled by $\Delta$ in one direction and $-\Delta$ in the other, and finally added back together.  You can see this in the following GIF:
[image]
Rotational symmetry precludes the existence of these two special directions, which means that the only contribution can come from the scalar and antisymmetric parts.

---

In slightly more mathematical language, the scalar part of $\sigma$ transforms (unsurprisingly) like a scalar, while the antisymmetric part transforms as a *pseudoscalar* in $2$ dimensions.  Under proper rotations, both of these parts are invariant.  The symmetric trace-free part transforms non-trivially under rotations, and so imposing rotational symmetry rules it out.